# bash filename globbing - operate on files starting with capital

Tags: bash, glob

Lets say I have a folder with the following jpeg-files:

```
adfjhu.jpg  Afgjo.jpg  
Bdfji.jpg   bkdfjhru.jpg
Cdfgj.jpg   cfgir.jpg
Ddfgjr.jpg  dfgjrr.jpg
```

How do I remove or list the files that starts with a capital?

This can be solved with a combination of `find`, `grep` and `xargs`.

But it is possible with normal file-globbing/pattern matching in bash?

cmd below doesn't work due to the fact that (as far as I can tell) LANG is set to `en_US`
and the collation order.

```
$ ls [A-Z]*.jpg
Afgjo.jpg  Bdfji.jpg  bkdfjhru.jpg  Cdfgj.jpg  cfgir.jpg  Ddfgjr.jpg  dfgjrr.jpg
```

This sort of works

```
$ ls +(A|B|C|D)*.jpg
Afgjo.jpg  Bdfji.jpg  Cdfgj.jpg  Ddfgjr.jpg
```

But I don't wanna do this for all characters A-Z for a general solution!

So is this possible?

cheers
//Fredrik

Comment: Interestingly enough, on my Linux box with LANG set to "en_US.UTF-8", "ls [A-Z]*" gives all the lower case ones as well, but on my Macintosh with LANG set to "en_US.UTF-8", "ls [A-Z]*" only gives uppper case names.  On neither box is LC_COLLATE set, so I don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should set your locale to the `C` (or `POSIX`) locale.

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls [A-Z]*.jpg
```

or

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls [[:upper:]]*.jpg
```

read here for more information: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/locale.html

Comment: Argh! I tried that one prior to my post but `LC_ALL=C ls [A-Z]*.jpg` lists all files for me! POSIX thingie [:upper:] works though! Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Use a bracket expression with a character class:

```
ls -l [[:upper:]]*
```

See [`man 7 regex`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex) for a list of character classes and other information.

From that page:

> Within a bracket expression, the name of a character class enclosed in '[:' and ':]' stands for the list of all characters belonging to that class. Standard character class names are:
>
> ```
> alnum    digit    punct  
> alpha    graph    space  
> blank    lower    upper  
> cntrl    print    xdigit
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`:

```
ls | grep -e ^[A-Z]
```

If you want make more use a `for` loop:

```
for i in $(ls | grep -e ^[A-Z]); do echo $i ;done
```